# Changing Delphi array range

Tags: arrays, database, delphi

I was wondering if there is a way that I can change the range of an array for my school project. Here's an example of the code (I have not tested it, but I'm positive that it will work):

```
procedure TfrmWelkom.LeesRekeningeIn(arrInLees : array [1..100,1..2] of string);
var
  iKol,iRy : Integer;
begin
  with dmAlleInlig do
  begin
    tblrekeninge.First;
    while not tblrekeninge.eof do
    begin
      for iKol := 1 to tblrekeninge.Eof do
        for iRy := 1 to 2 do
        begin
          arrInLees[iKol] := tblrekeninge['GebruikersNaam'];
          arrInLees[iRy] := tblrekeninge['Wagwoord'];
          tblrekeninge.Next;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, my range of the array is `1..100` and `1..2`. I want the 100 to be changed according to the amount of information that is in the database.

I hope you will understand.

If you have a better way to read information from an Access Database, please share....

I'm new to StackOverflow, so please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: Use a dynamic array

Comment: This is fairly standard basic stuff. Google Delphi open arrays and Delphi dynamic arrays.

Comment: As @JerryDodge says: please don't post a link to a picture of your code. Copy the code from the editor and paste it into your question (you can edit your own question). To format it as code, simply select it and press the `{}` toolbar button in the question editor in your browser. Code can be copied and examined by the reader that way. External links can go stale (and often do). Code in a question doesn't.

Comment: @Dsm: what are "Delphi open arrays"? If you mean open array *parameters* then say so. "Open arrays" as such don't exist. Dynamic arrays do, of course.

Comment: I'm new to this, forgive me

Comment: @E.T, just edit your question and insert the code as text.

Comment: `procedure TfrmWelkom.LeesRekeningeIn(arrInLees : array [1..100,1..2] of string);` will most definitely **not** work. You can't define a parameter like that. You must first define a type.

Comment: Using a dynamic array, you can set its size to record count  by Setlength command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several mistakes in it:

- your array parameter is using an illegal declaration that will not compile:

  > [DCC Error] E2029 'OF' expected but '[' found
- `iKol := 1 to tblrekeninge.Eof do` will not work, you probably meant to use `iKol := 1 to 100 do` instead.
- `arrInLees[iKol] := ...` should be `arrInLees[iKol][iRy] := ...` instead.  But really, your whole inner `iRy` loop should be be removed completely, it is not filling the array properly.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TRekeningeArray = array [1..100, 1..2] of string;

function TfrmWelkom.LeesRekeningeIn(var arrInLees : TRekeningeArray): Integer;
var
  iKol : Integer;
begin
  with dmAlleInlig do
  begin
    tblrekeninge.First;
    iKol := 1;
    while (not tblrekeninge.Eof) and (iKol <= 100) do
    begin
      arrInLees[iKol][1] := tblrekeninge['GebruikersNaam'];
      arrInLees[iKol][2] := tblrekeninge['Wagwoord'];
      Inc(iKol);
      tblrekeninge.Next;
    end;
  end;
  Result := iKol - 1; // the actual number of records in the array
end;
```

Which you can then tweak to use a dynamic array instead of a fixed array:

```
type
  TRekeninge = record
    GebruikersNaam : string;
    Wagwoord : string;
  end;
  TRekeningeArray = array of TRekeninge;

function TfrmWelkom.LeesRekeningeIn(var arrInLees : TRekeningeArray): Integer;
var
  iKol, iLengte : Integer;
begin
  with dmAlleInlig do
  begin
    tblrekeninge.First;
    iLengte := tblrekeninge.RecordCount;
    SelLength(arrInLees, iLengte);
    iKol := 0;
    while (not tblrekeninge.Eof) and (iKol < iLengte) do
    begin
      arrInLees[iKol].GebruikersNaam := tblrekeninge['GebruikersNaam'];
      arrInLees[iKol].Wagwoord := tblrekeninge['Wagwoord'];
      Inc(iKol);
      tblrekeninge.Next;
    end;
  end;
  Result := iKol;
end;
```

Comment: He or she is **not using an open array**, not in the code posted. You link to my article, but the parameter doesn't match what I write there.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Actually, it DID match something in your article - a Note in the "Confusion" section: "*Note: You should not forget that in Delphi, **parameters can ony be declared with type specifications, and not with type declarations**. So the following formal parameters, which would be type declarations, are not possible: ...*".  It matched the first example you gave.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: It did not match the „open array parameters“ in my article. After all, you called it open array. Thanks for the correction.